# Lavender is taking off!

Tags: plant-care, outdoor

My lavender has just exploded with new stems this spring. I didn’t expect it would grow so tall. Do you think it’s time to repot so it spreads out? I have a much larger space I could fill with it if it has the potential to grow really large. Also not sure if these stems are a sign of flowering, I’ve never had that luck before. [image]

Comment: Yes, it's going to flower.

Comment: The little 'bushy' bits at the end of the stems are the flowers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The taller stems are flower stems; later, when the flowers have finished, you'll be clipping them back right at the base, where the leaves are, and taking a little leaf material too to try to keep the plant from going woody too soon. It does not yet look like it needs a bigger pot, and it's best not to pot on while it has flowering stems anyway.

As for how wide and tall the whole plant can get, that's dependent on which variety of lavender you have - there are dwarf varieties that spread only 1-1.5 feet and others which have a height and spread of around 3-4 feet, if they are planted in the ground. In pots, they are unlikely to achieve full height and spread.

Comment: Exciting! Thank you!